# Why config.json changes are not afected in localhost?

Tags: bigcommerce

I have done some setting changes on store via `https://store-xxxxxxxxx.mybigcommerce.com/manage`

The i have take pull in local using `stencil pull`, so i can see the file `config.json` is updated via `git status`.

But when i run using `stencil start` via `localhost:3000`, this changes can't see.

Comment: Hi there, have you tried to restart stencil? As in if you're using stencil start to run your storefront locally, you make the config change and then stop and restart stencil by exiting the command and restating the command?

Comment: Yes, I tried it many times, but doesn't work.

Comment: This is definitely not expected, as saved changes in the config.json should be apparent via localhost. Have you tried to make changes in the config.json directly then saving to see if those are coming through, in comparison to the changes made via page builder.

Answer (score 0):

seems like this is a bug. try restarting Stencil CLI  after making changes to `config.json` like suggested [here](https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/question/0D51B00003olJES/localhost-changes-not-updating?language=en_US).

and if that's not working it seems like there is nothing else to do than wait :)